# ODS Type 3 Proc Surveyselect

Tags: sas, ods

I am trying to write ods output while using the following macro:

```
   %let class1=X1   X2
   %let &new_var=X3 X4

   options mprint mlogic symbolgen;
%macro LogitBoot(data = , dv = , iv = ,class=, n = );
proc sql noprint;
create table logit_result
(iv char(10), prob num format = 6.4,
sig1 num format = 4., sig2 num format = 4.,
sig3 num format = 4., sig4 num format = 4.);
select count(*) into :sample from &data;
quit;
%do i = 1 %to &n;

proc surveyselect data = training method = urs out = &data._tmp n = &sample
noprint;
run;
proc logistic data = &data._tmp desc;
freq numberhits;
class &class;
model &dv = &iv;
ods output type3 = model_tmp;
run;
proc sql;
 insert into logit_result
 select
 upcase(effect) as iv, ProbChiSq as prob,
 case when ProbChiSq <= 0.01 then 1 else 0 end as sig1,
 case when ProbChiSq > 0.01 and ProbChiSq <= 0.05 then 1 else 0 end as sig2,
 case when ProbChiSq > 0.05 and ProbChiSq <= 0.1 then 1 else 0 end as sig3,
 case when ProbChiSq > 0.1 then 1 else 0 end as sig4
 from model_tmp;
 quit;
%end;
proc summary data = logit_result nway;
class iv;
output out = out_table (drop = _type_ rename = (_freq_ = count))
sum(sig1) = sum(sig2) = sum(sig3) = sum(sig4) = ;
run;
%mend LogitBoot;
```

%LogitBoot(data =training , dv = Target,  class=&class1,iv =&new_var , n = 2);
But I keep getting the following warning :

WARNING: Output 'type3' was not created. Make sure that the output object name, label, or path is spelled correctly. Also, verify
that the appropriate procedure options are used to produce the requested output object. For example, verify that the
NOPRINT option is not used.

Can someone help?

Comment: According to the documentation type3 is not a suitable ods table name (https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveyselect_sect021.htm)

Comment: Sorry my bad I am actually using it for the proc logistic but it still doesn't generate

Comment: Can you post sample data and working code?  Your current code has extra PROC statement at top. Does not have any calls to the macro it defines.  Also you need to set the ODS OUTPUT before the proc runs and not after.

Comment: Hi Tom I have edited my post can you please take a look now?

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of SAS, the `type3` table has been removed.  You can see that in the most up-to-date doc [here](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=14.2&docsetTarget=statug_logistic_details97.htm&locale=en).

Try the `ModelANOVA` table.  It is described in the documentation as

> Joint or Type 3 tests of effects

I don't have an old version of SAS to test against, so I cannot tell you if the table structure is the same.  If not, you will have to modify your code appropriately.

Comment: Thanks !! I figured it out. The different levels of the class variables used in the model needs to be specified using the "ref=" statement & it will generate the Type 3 analysis.

Comment: It might help others if you posted this comment as an answer. You could just detail what lines of your original code needed to change.

Comment: @user6016731 This is not correct, please see my post on communities.sas.com that illustrates this. DomPazz solution is correct.